# Консольная графика на С++

Tags: графика, консоль, c++, graphics

Есть задание вывести на экран LOGIC звездочками ("*"). Как это можно реализовать? я могу только букву L вывести

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
      cout << '*' << endl;
cout << "*****" << endl;
```

Есть еще задание посложнее, вывести на экран анимацию, LOGIC появляется и увеличивается в масштабе

Вроде слышал я о какойто библиотеке дополнительной, помогите кто может

---

У меня получилось!! Без всяких массивов, только как теперь шаг сделать поменьше чтоб увеличивался не всего лишь 3 раза а раз 10

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void prob(int i)
{
     for(int k = 0; k < i; k++)
             cout << ' ';
}

void zvezd(int i)
{
     for(int k = 0; k < i; k++)
             cout << '*';
}

void clear(int i)
{
     for(int k = 0; k < i; k++)
             cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
    /* Без анимации
    cout << "*       *     **   *   ** " << endl;
    cout << "*      * *   *     *  *  *" << endl;
    cout << "*     *   *  * **  *  *   " << endl;
    cout << "*      * *   *  *  *  *  *" << endl;
    cout << "****    *     **   *   ** " << endl;
    */

    for(int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
    {
            // 1 stroka
            zvezd(1*i);
            prob(7*i);
            zvezd(1*i);
            prob(5*i);
            zvezd(2*i);
            prob(3*i);
            zvezd(1*i);
            prob(3*i);
            zvezd(2*i);
            prob(1*i);

            cout << endl;

            // 2 stroka
            zvezd(1*i);
            prob(6*i);
            zvezd(1*i);
            prob(1*i);
            zvezd(1*i);
            prob(3*i);
            zvezd(1*i);
            prob(5*i);
            zvezd(1*i);
            prob(2*i);
            zvezd(1*i);
            prob(2*i);
            zvezd(1*i);

            cout << endl;

            // 3 stroka
            zvezd(1*i);
            prob(5*i);
            zvezd(1*i);
            prob(3*i);
            zvezd(1*i);
            prob(2*i);
            zvezd(1*i);
            prob(1*i);
            zvezd(2*i);
            prob(2*i);
            zvezd(1*i);
            prob(2*i);
            zvezd(1*i);
            prob(3*i);

            cout << endl;

            // 4 stroka
            zvezd(1*i);
            prob(6*i);
            zvezd(1*i);
            prob(1*i);
            zvezd(1*i);
            prob(3*i);
            zvezd(1*i);
            prob(2*i);
            zvezd(1*i);
            prob(2*i);
            zvezd(1*i);
            prob(2*i);
            zvezd(1*i);
            prob(2*i);
            zvezd(1*i);

            cout << endl;

            // 5 stroka
            zvezd(4*i);
            prob(4*i);
            zvezd(1*i);
            prob(5*i);
            zvezd(2*i);
            prob(3*i);
            zvezd(1*i);
            prob(3*i);
            zvezd(2*i);
            prob(1*i);

            cout << endl;

            clear(19);
            Sleep(900);
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Получившаяся программа "одноразовая", т.е. чтобы вывести другую надпись нужно довольно сильно ее переделать.

Comment: Полностью согласен

Comment: http://patorjk.com/software/taag/#p=display&c=c&f=3x5&t=TEST 
Да, даже это уже кто-то реализовал до вас. Есть даже умельцы которые делают целые 2D движки в которых вместо пикселей цветные буквы из терминала. http://caca.zoy.org/wiki/libcaca http://aa-project.sourceforge.net/aalib/

Comment: молодцы кто реализовал, мне то просто не результат был важен, а процесс реализации

Comment: А теперь надо написать генератор таких программ для разных текстов и размеров (передавать в параметрах).

Компьютеры сейчас быстрые, компиляция пройдет, глазом моргнуть не успеешь.

Comment: @risonyo, самое интересное, что функционально ваша программ НИЧЕМ не отличается от закомментированных строк, но на порядок сложнее и неочевиднее.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@risonyo](/users/8533/risonyo), попробуйте обобщить (первую) задачу и все упростится. Представьте, что Вам требуется вывести текст (передаваемый в аргументе функции как строка символов) на экран, рисуя его звездочками. Для простоты предположим, что мы будем выводить столько символов текста, сколько влезает на экран.

Тогда, для представления каждого символа Вам понадобится хранить матрицу из звездочек (а можно и других символов) и пробелов. Также нужно хранить ширину (количество колонок) каждой матрицы. Высота **`L`** (количество печатаемых строк) пусть будет одинакова для всех матриц.

Тогда задача сводится к двум вложенным циклам. Внешний (скажем по **`i`**) выполняется **`L`** раз. Во внутреннем цикле (перебор символов текста) формируется строка (размером в ширину экрана) из звездочек и пробелов, в соответствии с i-ой строкой очередного выводимого символа.

Т.е. берете очередной символ текста, находите (например, по его коду) соответствующую ему матрицу и добавляете i-ю строку этой матрицы в конец формируемой строки для печати. Вставляете пробел. Если вылезаете за ширину экрана, то выходите из внутреннего цикла, не смотря на то, что не все символы текста еще обработаны.

После этого внутреннего цикла строка для печати готова и Вы просто выводите ее на экран.

Такая вот идея. *Дальше ее можно развивать в сторону увеличения масштаба.*

Как представить матрицы символов в программе придумайте сами. Думаю надо посмотреть в сторону *struct* и массива указателей на них. Для начала ограничьтесь символами ascii (т.е. кодами меньше 128).

Comment: Да, я видел ответ @mega, и по сути описал его словами, увидев, что ТС изобразил в update своего вопроса.

Comment: Только я не делаю проверки на выход за пределы `screen`-буфера. В таком случае, я бы предпочел перейти на новую строку, а не обрезать текст (см. `echo3`)

Answer (score 2):

Заведите символьную битовую матрицу Вашего алфавита (для этих 5 букв), после чего, пройдитесь по каждой - двойным циклом с выводом `пробела` - для значения `нуля` и `звездочки` - для `единицы`.

Т.е, что-то вроде такого(псевдокод):

```
matrix abc[255];
...
void echo1( const char*pszText, int scale ){
  ...
  for( y = 0 ; y < cy ; ++y ){
    for( p = pszText ; *p ; ++p ){
      for( x = 0 ; x < cx ; ++x ){
        put_char( abc[*p][x][y] ? '*' : ' ' );
        for( s = scale ; s-- ; put_char( ' ' ) );
      }
      put_char( ' ' );   
    }
    for( s = scale + 1 ; s-- ; put_char( '\r' ), put_char( '\n' ) );
  }
}
```

---

```
void echo2( const char*pszText, int scale ){
  ...
  for( y = 0 ; y < cy * ( scale + 1 ) ; ++y ){
    for( p = pszText ; *p ; ++p ){
      for( x = 0 ; x < cx ; ++x ){
        ch = abc[*p][x][y/scale] ? '*' : ' ';
        for( s = scale + 1 ; s-- ; put_char( ch ) );
      }
      put_char( ' ' );
    }
    put_char( '\r' );
    put_char( '\n' );
  }
}
```

---

```
void _echo3( const char*pszText, int length, int scale ){
  ...
  for( y = 0 ; y < cy * ( scale + 1 ) ; ++y ){
    for( p = pszText, counter = length ; counter-- ; ++p ){
      for( x = 0 ; x < cx ; ++x ){
        ch = abc[*p][x][y/scale] ? '*' : ' ';
        for( s = scale + 1 ; s-- ; put_char( ch ) );
      }
      put_char( ' ' );
    }
    put_char( '\r' );
    put_char( '\n' );
  }
}
/**
    @param scale - масштаб символа (в символах: 0 - *, 1 - **, 2 - ***, ...)
    @param screen_width - ширина экранного буфера (в символах)
    @param indent - расстояние между строками (в символах), в случае перевода строки
 */
bool echo3( const char*pszText, int screen_width, int scale = 0, int indent = 0 ){
  ...
  char_len = ( scale + 1 ) * cx;
  text_len = strlen( pszText ) * char_len;
  if( 0 == ( line_len = screen_width / char_len ) ){
    //  если и одного символа не вывести - печаль
    return false;
  }
  for( lines = text_len / screen_width ; lines-- ; pszText += line_len ){
    _echo3( pszText, line_len, scale );
    for( i = indent + 1 ; i-- ; put_char( '\r' ), put_char( '\n' ) );
  }
  if( text_len % screen_width ){
    echo2( pszText, scale );
    for( i = indent + 1 ; i-- ; put_char( '\r' ), put_char( '\n' ) );
  } 
  return true;
}
```

Comment: т.е. предлагаешь записать эти буквы в массив, типо:

<pre>
*        *
*       *
*       *
*        *
******    *   и т.д.?
</pre>

Comment: а как тогда 2 задание реализовать? думаю такой способ не подойдет

Comment: Анимация решается разрежением этих звездочек между строками/символами, число которых можно дополнительно указать в параметре функции `echo`

Answer (score 2):

Есть такой вариант:
сделать покадровую анимацию, записать каждый кадр в файл и выводить их на экран последовательно.

есть другой вариант - написать "движок", использующий `WinApi` для вывода в консоль, преемущество такого способа - скорость вывода (`std::cout` все же довольно медленно рисует), возможность нарисовать символ где угодно и контролировать его цвет.
для этого варианта вот пример: [Чтение и запись блоков символов и атрибутов](http://vsokovikov.narod.ru/New_MSDN_API/Console/conattr.htm)

Comment: Конечно же круто, но у меня еще не тот "уровень знаний"

Comment: ну как, оно проще чем кажется, если совсем лень разбираться в дебрях винапи, то покадровый вариант - самое оно, вывести содержимое файла на экран труда не должно составить. просто по очереди разные файлы рисовать надо и все.

Comment: Прежде чем "соваться в дебри", надо наверное нарисовать сами кадры. Мне опять вспоминается решение "hello world" от "админа" через удаленный сервер.  
 --  
Но мы же не ищем легких путей :))